# bash auto-complete separates strings

Tags: ubuntu, bash, autocomplete, elementaryos

Let's say I'd like to cd to the directory containing all albums by the artist "The Ghost of a Saber Tooth Tiger" so I start typing

```
cd ~/Music/The\ Ghost
```

and hit [TAB] [TAB]. At this point bash complete changes my command to

```
cd ~/Music/The Ghost of a Saber Tooth Tiger
```

which is useless. I'd like it to complete it to

```
cd ~/Music/The\ Ghost\ of\ a\ Saber\ Tooth\ Tiger/
```

instead. I've already tried transplanting a different `/etc/bash_completion`, which fixed the problem but now I get a bunch of `bash: [: =: unary operator expected` errors when I start a new shell. Any suggestions?

I'm using bash version 4.2.25, on elementaryOS Luna (a fork of Ubuntu 12.04)

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you could remove the package and re-install it to get the default files back:

```
sudo apt-get purge bash-completion && sudo apt-get install bash-completion
```

Comment: I executed this and the problem persists